# Android Studio can't start a daemon process

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with "gradle" when I create a new project. How can I fix this? Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run Android Studio as Administrator. It worked for me. Remember to have enough free memory on your device.

This link has some further explanation and more solutions, thank you: 
http://dominiksymonowicz.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-solve-error-errorunable-to-start.html